# Waterline ORM (sails.js) "where or" - effiency

Tags: javascript, orm, sails.js

I am using Waterline ORM (sails.js), and the query "where or".

I have a query with a multiple 'or' in the 'where' section,
that checks
if any of 2 specific fields are equal to a value in an array

and should return that item,

lets say the array is `var array = ["Jack", "Kyle","Stan", "Randy"]`

and the fields are 'name' and 'nickName' , and the query runs -

```
where 
 'name' or 'nickName' equals "Jack"
or
'name' or 'nickName' equals "Kyle"
or
'name' or 'nickName' equals "Stan"
or
'name' or 'nickName' equals "Randy"
```

Now the query runs extremely slow, and I wish to make it faster.

is there a way to make the query faster using sails.js? by the waterline ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await Users.find({ 
  where: { 
    or: [
      { name: ["Jack", "Kyle","Stan", "Randy"] },
      { nickName: ["Jack", "Kyle","Stan", "Randy"] },
    ]
  } 
})
```

**or** : modifier to match any of the nested rule sets you specify as an array of query pairs.

```
{ name: ["Jack", "Kyle","Stan", "Randy"] }
```

This is more or less equivalent to "IN" queries in SQL

More about
[**Waterline query language**](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language#?or-predicate)

Comment: @Elikill58 Okay )